# Date-time comparison

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I can check whether time A is later than time B or not with

```
A.time() > B.time():
```

But what's the trick to doing the same past midnight?

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

movies = [
"13:00 Alien Beetroot",
"15:30 Bananas Go Bad!",
"17:45 Cheerleader Lake",
"19:00 Yoghurt Spoon Eater",
"21:10 Zombie A Go-Go",
"23:30 Shark Snacks VI",
"02:15 Drive-In Dinosaur Disaster"
]

myTime = "18:30"
myDate = "Wed 03 November 2015"
cineDate = "Wed 03 November 2015" 
t = datetime.strptime(myDate + " " + myTime, "%a %d %B %Y %H:%M")

for i in range(0, len(movies)):
  sp = movies[i].split(" ", 1)
  tim = sp[0]
  mov = sp[1]
  show = datetime.strptime(cineDate + " " + tim, "%a %d %B %Y %H:%M")

  if show.time() >= t.time():
    print tim + " " + mov
```

I would expect the script to list all movies after 18:30, but it misses the last one out. Should I store the date time for all the movies and do a comparison that way or is there an easier way around?

Comment: drop `.time()` call and use [this algorithm to adjust `show` time based on the time for the previous movie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33561802/4279)

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that your day ends at 6 AM (for example) next date. In other words, "02:15 Drive-In Dinosaur Disaster" belongs to the next date but for you it's the same date though it's after midnight. If you need to compare hours and minutes only, you can reduce your datetime by 6 hours like this:

```
movies = [
"13:00 Alien Beetroot",
"15:30 Bananas Go Bad!",
"17:45 Cheerleader Lake",
"19:00 Yoghurt Spoon Eater",
"21:10 Zombie A Go-Go",
"23:30 Shark Snacks VI",
"02:15 Drive-In Dinosaur Disaster"
]

myTime = (18, 30) # hours and minutes

myTime_reduced = ((myTime[0] - 6) % 24, myTime[1]) # the mentioned reduce

for i in range(0, len(movies)):
    sp = movies[i].split(" ", 1)
    tim = sp[0]
    mov = sp[1]

    h, m = tim.split(':')

    h_reduced = (h - 6) % 24 # the mentioned reduce

    if h_reduced > myTime_reduced[0] or (h_reduced == myTime_reduced[0] and m > myTime_reduced[1]):
        print tim + " " + mov
```